# duplicate data showing in UITableView after UIViewController being dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates

**Problems :**
UITableview populate duplicate data even after removing the array when it dismiss

**Expected output:**

UITableview populate data based on itenary items in array

**Actual output:**

UITableView populates the correct amount output when the user selects the first location in DiscoverVC but when the user selects another location, the tableview append the itenary data that the user-selected previouly.

**Summary:**

I have 3VC in my project, first vc (DiscoverVC), will call api to populate data in UICollectionView, I implement UICollectionView Delegate to move to another screen with segue, in prepare segue I pass data from the first vc to second vc (ItenaryVC), in second vc i have 2 view inside it. One normal vc and the second is floating panel (ItenaryFP). When second vc loads up it will make API calls base on Location object that had been pass from first vc and pass the data to the third vc which is floating panel (ItenaryFP) through delegate in ItenaryVC.

**PS;** I use custom cell for the tableview and have, I also already try to remove the array from viewWillAppear and viewDidDissapear but it's still not working

[GIF of how the issues occurs](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/59039044/131853935-76ca78e9-4891-4e67-8658-7c66c1ae264a.gif)

Here is a summary of my code

**DiscoverVC.swift**

```
  class DiscoverVC : UIViewController {
    //MARK:- IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private var locationResult = [Location]()
    private var selectedAtRow : Int!
    
    //MARK:- Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        renderView()
        getLocations()
    }
    
    private func renderView() {
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: R.nib.discoverCell.name, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: R.reuseIdentifier.discoverCell.identifier)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    private func getLocations(location : String = "locations") {
        
        NetworkManager.shared.getLocations(for: location) {  [weak self] location in
            
            switch location {
            
            case .success(let locations):
                self?.updateDiscoverUI(with: locations)
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateDiscoverUI(with locations : [Location]) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.locationResult.append(contentsOf: locations)
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

//MARK:- Delegate
extension DiscoverVC : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        selectedAtRow = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: R.segue.discoverVC.goToDetails, sender: self)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ItenaryVC else { return}
        // Passing location object to ItenaryVC
        destinationVC.locationName = locationResult[selectedAtRow]
        destinationVC.imageURL = locationResult[selectedAtRow].image
      
        // Remove tab bar when push to other vc
        destinationVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        
    }
}
```

**ItenaryVC.swift**

```
   protocol ItenaryVCDelegate : AnyObject {
        func didSendItenaryData(_ itenaryVC : ItenaryVC, with itenary : [[Days]])
        func didSendLocationData(_ itenaryVC : ItenaryVC, with location : Location) 
    }
    
    class ItenaryVC: UIViewController {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!
        
        var fpc : FloatingPanelController!
        var imageURL : URL?
        var locationName: Location?
    
        weak var delegate : ItenaryVCDelegate?
        
        //MARK:- Life Cycle
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            setupCard()
            setupView()
        }
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            // Call API for data
            getItenaries(at: locationName!.itenaryName)
            print("ItenaryVC Appear")
        }
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            locationName = nil
        }
       
        
    }
    
    //MARK:- Network Request
    extension ItenaryVC {
        
        func getItenaries(at itenaries : String = "Melaka"){
            print("itenaries  : \(itenaries)")
            NetworkManager.shared.getItenaries(for: itenaries) { [weak self] itenary in
                switch itenary {
                
                case .success(let itenary):
                    // print(itenary)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // Passing data to itenaryFP
                        self?.delegate?.didSendItenaryData(self! , with: itenary)
                    }
                    
                    print(itenaries.count)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK:- Private methods
    extension ItenaryVC {
        
        private func setupView() {
         
            
            backgroundImage.downloaded(from: imageURL!)
            backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            // Passing data to itenaryFP
            delegate?.didSendLocationData(self, with: locationName!)
        }
        
        private func setupCard() {
            guard let itenaryFlotingPanelVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "itenaryPanel") as? ItenaryFP else { return}
            // Initliase delegate to Floating Panel, create strong reference to Panel
            self.delegate = itenaryFlotingPanelVC
          
            fpc = FloatingPanelController()
            fpc.set(contentViewController: itenaryFlotingPanelVC)
            fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
            fpc.delegate = self
            fpc.layout = self
            
        }
    }
```

**ItenaryFP.swift**

```
   class ItenaryFP: UIViewController{
    
    
    var itenaries = [[Days]]()
    var location : Location?
    
    //MARK:- : Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ItrenaryFP viewDidLoad, itenaries : \(itenaries.count), location : \(location)")
        renderView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        itenaries.removeAll()
        itenaryTableView.reloadData()

    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
         
            self.itenaries.removeAll()
            print("ItenarFP dissapear, itenaries :\(self.itenaries.count), location : \(self.location)")
            self.location = nil
            self.itenaryTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    
   private func renderView() {
        itenaryTableView.register(UINib(nibName: R.nib.itenaryCell.name, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: R.nib.itenaryCell.identifier)
        
        itenaryTableView.dataSource = self
        itenaryTableView.delegate = self
        
        locDescHC.constant = locDesc.contentSize.height
    }
}

//MARK:- Data source
extension ItenaryFP : UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return itenaries.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itenaries[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell : ItenaryCell = itenaryTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: R.nib.itenaryCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ItenaryCell
     
        let listOfItenaries = itenaries[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        
        cell.cellContent(for: listOfItenaries)
    
        return cell
    }
}



//MARK:- ItenaryVC Delegate
extension ItenaryFP : ItenaryVCDelegate {
    
    
    func didSendLocationData(_ itenaryVC: ItenaryVC, with location: Location) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.locationLabel.text = location.locationName
            self.locDesc.text = location.description
            self.sloganLabel.text = location.slogan
        }
    }
    
    
    func didSendItenaryData(_ itenaryVC: ItenaryVC, with itenary: [[Days]]) {
        
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.itenaries.append(contentsOf: itenary)
            self.itenaryTableView.reloadData()
            print("itenary \(self.itenaries.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set some breakpoints, or add some `print(...)` statements, where you *think* your array is being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
self.itenaries = itenary
```

Instead of:

```
self.itenaries.append(contentsOf: itenary)
```